# error in reading a text file (containing HTML tags) and appending into new rows of a dataframe

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table, rvest, readr

I am trying to read all the text files in a folder and what I am doing:

1. read each of the text files from a specific html tag "TEXT"
2. store the data frame where column name is "MyText"
3. append the next row after reading from next text file (as above)

And my code is:

```
library(dplyr); library(readr); library(rvest); library(data.table); 

# List all the text files in the folder
files = list.files(pattern="*.txt")

# read from file and append to rows
tbl = lapply(files, read_html %>% html_nodes("text") %>%  html_text() ) %>% bind_rows()
```

This is throwing me an error:

```
Error in UseMethod("xml_find_all") : 
  no applicable method for 'xml_find_all' applied to an object of class "function"
```

Can someone please help in correcting where am I wrong?

Comment: Try `tbl = lapply(files, function(x) read_html(x) %>% html_nodes("text") %>%  html_text() ) %>% bind_rows()`

Comment: @AndrewGustar thanks for helping me out: but i got this error `Error in bind_rows_(x, .id) : Argument 1 must have names`

Answer (score 2):

The heart of the problem is that `read_html %>% html_nodes("text") %>%  html_text()` does not evaluate to a function. You could use magrittr lambda by starting the pipeline with a dot, e.g. `. %>% read_html %>% html_nodes("text") %>%  html_text()`.

Then eventually `html_text()` will give you a vector, not a data frame you can feed to `bind_rows`.

Instead of the `lapply`/`bind_rows`, you can use `purrr::map_df()`:

```
library(purrr)
library(rvest)
map_df( files, ~ {
  file   <- .x
  MyText <- read_html(file) %>%
    html_nodes("text") %>%
    html_text() 
  tibble( file, MyText )
} )
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution. I have checked on my laptop and it is working:

```
# ________________ BELOW STEPS READS THE DATA SETS AND CREATES A DATAFRAME _______________________ 

# set default folder first
setwd("drive/you/folder/location")    

# read text files from the folders 
files <-list.files()

# create an empty dataframe
data <- data.frame()

# read files one by one and create dataframe
for (f in files) {

  # read as HTML
  dat <- read_html(f)

  # from data extract everything within <TEXT> and </TEXT> tags
  dat2 <- data.frame(Text = dat %>% html_nodes("text") %>%  html_text() , stringsAsFactors = F)

  # create new columns
  dat3 <- data.frame(Text = strsplit(dat2$Text, " \\| ")[[1]], stringsAsFactors = F)

  # create new columns from "Text"
  dat4 <- data.frame(Text = strsplit(dat3$Text[[3]], ":")[[1]], stringsAsFactors = F)

  # merge all the columns and rows after some basic text cleaning/processing
  NewsData <- data.frame(News_Paper = trimws(dat3$Text[1], which = "both"),
                         News_Class = trimws(dat3$Text[2], which = "both"),
                         Author_Location_Date = gsub("\r?\n|\r|\t|\\s+", " ", trimws(dat4$Text[1], which = "both")),
                         Text = gsub("\r?\n|\r|\t|\\s+", " ", trimws(dat4$Text[2], which = "both"))
  ) 

  # merge all the rows from remaining text files in the folder, one by one
  data <- rbind.data.frame(data, NewsData, make.row.names = F, stringsAsFactors = F)

} 

 # remove the unwanted dataframes
 rm(list=c("dat2", "dat3", "dat4"))


# ________________ END OF THE ABOVE STEPS ___________________________________________________
```

I hope this will help you.

Comment: perfect. this does the same I wanted.